# Will Sodium Silicate dissolve in acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I recently discovered (through Wikipedia)  that water glass / sodium Silicate dissolves in water (22 g / 100 ml @ 25 degrees and 160 g / 100 ml @ 80 degrees).

Doesn't that mean it'll dissolve in acetone?

Comment: Welcome to SE. The statement you gave and what you're asking aren't really related. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: I would like to infuse wood with water glass.  Acetone is used to dissolve epoxies to a very thin consistency.  I was hoping that since water glass is soluble in water, it can dissolve in acetone, as well.  Or at least it won't react if I added acetone to the water glass solution (of water and sodium silicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sodium silicate partially dissolve in acetone solution forming a homogeneous mixture. Hence, it is miscible in acetone solution. From [pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Sodium_metasilicate#section=Solubility):

> GLASS FORM SOL IN STEAM UNDER PRESSURE; **PARTIALLY MISCIBLE WITH
>   PRIMARY ALC & KETONES**; MISCIBLE WITH SOME POLYHYDRIC ALC
>
> *Sax, N.I. and R.J. Lewis, Sr. (eds.). Hawley's Condensed Chemical Dictionary. 11th ed. New York: Van Nostrand Reinhold Co., **1987**.,
>   p. 1072*

Comment: Well acetone is ketone, isn't it? You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: _sigh_ Dissolving means forming homogeneous solution....